# When calling a C++ DLL from a C program it crashes when I try to access call parameter pointer in the DLL

Tags: c++, c, dll, parameters, crash

I've written a C program that uses an array of pointers to functions.  The
functions are both inside my program and in loadable DLL's.  My problem comes
when I try to use a DLL that came from a C++ program.  Here's a simplified
snippit of the code in the C++ (DLL) program:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define EXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#endif

typedef struct { float x,y,z; } VECT;

EXPORT VECT norm(OBJECT *obj, RAY ray, float t, VECT *pt, RGB *col)
{
VECT npt;
...
*pt = npt;  /* give pt a new value */
...
}
```

The problem is it crashes as soon as I try to do anything with pt.  It's not
NULL, but if I try to write to it or even just access it's members, it
crashes.  I've kind of solved the problem by converting the C++ code to C, but
I would really like to know why this crashes.  If I take out any attempt to
access pt, the program works fine (except for missing the functionality that
would come with a correct pt).  BTW, here's another weird thing -
when I do the following in the now C DLL code:

```
EXPORT VECT norm(OBJECT *obj, RAY ray, float t, VECT *pt, RGB *col)
```

it crashes.  But if I do:

```
EXPORT VECT norm(obj, ray, t, pt, col)
OBJECT *obj;
VECT *pt;
RAY ray;
float t;
RGB *col;
```

It doesn't crash.  Is there any way to get C++ to accept the second way of
specifying parameters?

Extra info, in case necessary...  I load the DLL functions with:

```
typedef struct Funcs
{
int (*inter)();
VECT (*normal)();
} FUNCS;

/*
 I've also tried:
typedef VECT (WINAPI *FNORMAL)(OBJECT *obj, RAY ray, float t, VECT *pt, RGB *col);
(FNORMAL)GetProcAddress...
*/

funcs[i].normal = (VECT *)GetProcAddress(dll2, "norm");
if (funcs[i].normal == NULL) { printf("Error: No norm procedure in '%s'\n", objstr); quit(); }
```

and call them with:

```
hit.normal = funcs[p->type].normal(p, ray, mint, &pt, &colm);
```

and I have tried fully specifying the type (instead of just VECT *) in the
GetProcAddress typecast.

I've even tried doing this in my linux version.  It crashes too, so it's not
a Windows only problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: When it crashes, is the value of `pt` the same in the caller's stack frame as inside the DLL/shared lib?

Comment: What is `normal`. Please show the declaration. In fact show us the declaration of the parameters that you pass. Also, that cast of `GetProcAddress` looks pretty bogus.

Comment: *Is there any way to get C++ to accept the second way of specifying parameters?* No there is not and the fact that you ask the question is a worrying sign. This sort of problem is easy enough to solve. But don't run around like a headless chicken trying things at random and opting for the first thing that doesn't crash. Understand the problem. Then solve it. Properly.

Comment: @Useless the values (of the pointer) are not the same.  I'm on linux right now, so I had to try with the linux version.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm not sure which "normal" you're referring to, but here's one of them:    typedef struct Funcs
    {
    int (*inter)();
    VECT (*normal)();
    } FUNCS;

Comment: I'm looking for the declaration of this `normal`: `funcs[p->type].normal(...)` and please add it to the question

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm not sure which "normal" you're referring to, but here's one of them:    typedef struct Funcs
    {
    int (*inter)();
    VECT (*normal)();
    } FUNCS; but I've also tried:typedef VECT (WINAPI *FNORMAL)(OBJECT *obj, RAY ray, float t, VECT *pt, RGB *col);
...(FNORMAL)GetProcAddress...  (assuming I didn't make any mistakes typing that in this stackoverflow box)

Comment: Don't use `WINAPI` which is `__stdcall` because the function would appear to be `__cdecl`. And please don't put this info in comments. It must appear in the question. As I said, you call the function through `funcs[p->type].normal(...)` and we need to see the declaration of that `normal`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan stackoverflow wouldn't let me edit comment again, that's why I had to do another comment.  WINAPI might be a problem for Windows, but I don't use that in the linux version.  My understanding is that both C and C++ default to __cdecl (but one should check), but I think, if I remember correctly, when I tried to specify __cdecl in the linux version, it wouldn't compile.  Haven't tried it with windows.  If I haven't answered all your questions (and other people's as well), it's taking me a bit to get the info together...

Comment: I think we've got enough information now. Did you read my answer yet?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I just read your answer.  I did previously try that, but with WINAPI added, so I'll try it without WINAPI.  BTW, I would have previously kept the form you mentioned (specifying parameter types in the declaration) but I was hesitant to change existing code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It works now, thanks for your help.  I edited my post to reflect the correct code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me the problem looks to stem from this declaration:

```
VECT (*normal)();
```

Here you are telling the compiler that `normal` is a pointer to a function that returns `VECT`. But you have not specified the parameters of the function and so the compiler will let you pass anything you like and it will attempt to work out what types to pass. That's very bad practice. You should stop doing this. Change the declaration of normal to be as follows:

```
VECT (*normal)(OBJECT *obj, RAY ray, float t, VECT *pt, RGB *col);
```

I cannot see anywhere in the C++ code that specifies calling convention so the assumption is that the default of `cdecl` is in effect. Obviously you need to match that on your side of the interface and if you specify no calling convention for your function pointer then you'll get the default of `cdecl` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure that all involved compile parameters are compatible during DLL build and client build.  Special attention is needed to:

- function call convention
- structure packing
- structure content

If all those looks fine, break at the point you call the function, and show everything you pass as argument. Then step into the function and check everything looks the same.